# Android BMI Calculator App error in intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to build a BMI calculator app, however, there seems to be a problem with using intent and the method getIntExtra(), as I always ended up getting the default value and not the value i passed in from another activity. 
Below is my code for the first activity

```
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);

            int weight = Integer.parseInt(weightText.getText().toString());
            int height = Integer.parseInt(heightText.getText().toString());

            intent.putExtra(USER_WEIGHT_EXTRA, weight);
            intent.putExtra(USER_HEIGHT_EXTRA, height);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Second Activity
the reason for double `height2 = (double)height/100` is to convert from cm to m.

```
    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    todo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todo);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    int weight = intent.getIntExtra("USER_WEIGHT_EXTRA", extraInt);
    int height = intent.getIntExtra("USER_HEIGHT_EXTRA", extraInt);

    double height2 = (double)height/100;
    double BMI = (weight*1.0)/(height2*height2);


    if (BMI < 20.0) {
        result.setText("You are: UNDERWEIGHT");
        todo.setText("You Should EAT MORE");
    } else if (BMI > 20.0 && BMI < 25.0) {
        result.setText("You are: NORMAL WEIGHT");
        todo.setText("You Should keep STAYING HEALTHY");
    } else if (BMI > 25) {
        result.setText("You are: OVERWEIGHT");
        todo.setText("You Should EXERCISE MORE");
    }
}
```

I am really stuck on this issue. Thank you all so much!

Comment: does `USER_WEIGHT_EXTRA = "USER_WEIGHT_EXTRA"`? same for height. You're using variables in your first activity and string literals in the second, could be the problem

Comment: the USER_WEIGHT_EXTRA in the first activity is a string variable that holds the string "USER_WEIGHT_EXTRA"

Comment: so the answer to my question is yes.

Comment: sorry haha that was what i meant to type as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first activity

```
 Intent in = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("USER_WEIGHT_EXTRA", weightText.getText().toString());
            in.putExtra("USER_HEIGHT_EXTRA", heightText.getText().toString());
            startActivity(in);`
```

for otherActivity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        int weight = Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("USER_WEIGHT_EXTRA"));
        int height = Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("USER_HEIGHT_EXTRA"));
```